# How can I clean up output from expect?

Tags: sed, terminal, expect, pty

Background: I'm using expect to connect between AMCE.sh and a managed network switch. I can connect to the switch via SSH, log in and issue commands but because of the way the switch manages SSL certificates I have to generate a new CSR every time. And the CSR is displayed on the terminal when you run the command, not as a file that can be downloaded. I need to save the CSR as a file so I can then feed it into ACME.sh.

Actual question:

I have the following in an expect script, the intention is to capture the output when the switch spits out the CSR into the file `$csr` and stops capturing when the ending line comes in.

```
send -- "command to generate CSR"
send -- "\r"
log_file -noappend $csr
expect -- "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"
log_file
```

This runs fine and I get a file, the issue is I get a bunch of extra garbage from the terminal (truncated example below, there's usually about a KB of extra garbage). I've tried feeding this through `sedz or` grep` but they don't seem to be able to handle the multi-line nature of what I want to extract from this.

```
^[[68;33Hc^[[68;33H^[[?25h^[~~~~~~*SNIP*~~~~~~[[?25h^[[68;1H^[[1;68r^[[68;1H-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----^M
MIICoDCCAYgCAQAwWzEfMB0GA1UEAxMWc3dpdGNoMS5ob21lLmdvc3NldC51azENM^M
AsGA1UECxMEaG9tZTEPMA0GA1UECh~~~~~~*SNIP*~~~~~~3lsRknVNg/ZAATDaRC^M
KR3EIZFS3izUZ/+3wYzni84QZcp6s6HmDaB2moRRarVThXnbcF0a5nvGQtU8j7jP1^M
J/RPoWPRQa7vsfnEgN+gjQj6EYHeD/uMKzYPWeKEyQ4VPmw7K/VLySbMg==^M
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----^M
^[[1;68r^[[68;1H^[[68;1H^[[2K^[[68;1H^[[?25h^[[68;1H^[[68;1Hswitch1.home.domain.uk(config)# ^[[68;1H^[[68;33H^[[68;1H^[[?25h^[[68;33H
```

If I run `cat test.csr` I get most of the file out cleanly but when I try to extract what I need using `sed` I can't get it to match what I need. Anxample of what I've tried `sed -E 's/([\s\S]*)(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----[\s\S]*-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----)([\s\S]*)/\2/m;t;d' test.csr`

```
[68;33Hc                         {end of command to generate CSR}
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICoDCCAYgCAQAwWzEfMB0GA1UEAxMWc3dpdGNoMS5ob21lLmdvc3NldC51azENM
AsGA1UECxMEaG9tZTE~~~~~~*SNIP*~~~~~~moRRarVThXnbcF0a5nvGQtU8j7jP1
J/RPoWPRQa7vsfnEgN+gjQj6EYHeD/uMKzYPWeKEyQ4VPmw7K/VLySbMg==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

So, long story short, how can I either get expect to give me clean output of just what I need, or how can I get `sed` or another tool to clean it up after the fact?

Comment: I realise this question is a bit of a mess, I've erred on the side of too much detail and I'm not sure what the best solution to my problem will be, hence the open ended question at the end. Thanks in advance to anyone that helps out!

Answer (score 2):

Capture the data you want with a regex for the expect pattern:

```
send -- "command to generate CSR"
send -- "\r"
expect -re "(-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-+.+-+END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-+)"
```

Then write just the captured text that to the file, removing the carrige re

```
set csr_text [regsub -all {\r\n} $expect_out(1,string) {\n}]
set fh [open $csr w]
puts $fh $csr_text
close $fh
```

Comment: Note, if the string to match is over 2000 characters, expect may fail to match it, as this is the default amount of buffered data kept (actually, it seems to be 2*this). It can be useful to add `match -d 10000` before the spawn to increase the size in that case.

Comment: So I've tried adding this but it isn't capturing the whole of the CSR text, I've added `match_max 10000` before I spawn the ssh process at meuh's suggestion but this is what I end up with saved. Is there anything else I need to add or something else I may have missed? `\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----9LaBngfOk/D8us/C/JVJmS0g==dqkn59`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully there's an answer just with `expect` but if not you can post-process with awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {
        beg = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"
        end = "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"
    }
    { sub(/\r$/,"") }
    sub(".*"beg,beg),sub(end".*",end)
' file
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICoDCCAYgCAQAwWzEfMB0GA1UEAxMWc3dpdGNoMS5ob21lLmdvc3NldC51azENM
AsGA1UECxMEaG9tZTEPMA0GA1UECh~~~~~~*SNIP*~~~~~~3lsRknVNg/ZAATDaRC
KR3EIZFS3izUZ/+3wYzni84QZcp6s6HmDaB2moRRarVThXnbcF0a5nvGQtU8j7jP
J/RPoWPRQa7vsfnEgN+gjQj6EYHeD/uMKzYPWeKEyQ4VPmw7K/VLySbMg==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I always advise not to use range expressions in favor of flags (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/1745001) but since you'll never use this for anything else I figure what the heck.